"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." postman django
Trying to do authorization on tokens
When I make a POST request through postman it gives an error
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        #'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]

manager.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def email_validator(self, email):
        try:
            validate_email(email)
        except ValidationError:
            raise ValueError(_("please ener a valid email"))
        
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        if email:
            email=self.normalize_email(email)
            self.email_validator(email)
        else:
            raise ValueError(_("an email adress is required"))
        if not username:
            raise ValueError(_("an username is required"))
        user=self.model(email=email, username=username, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_verified", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("is staff must be true for admin user"))
        
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("is superuser must be true for admin user"))
        user = self.create_user(
            email, username, password, **extra_fields
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .utils import send_code_to_user

class RegisterUserView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class=UserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user_data=request.data
        serializer=self.serializer_class(data=user_data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            serializer.save()
            user=serializer.data
            send_code_to_user(user['email'])
            return Response({
                'data':user,
                'message':f'hi{user.username}'
            }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Users


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Users
        fields=['email', 'username', 'password', 'password2']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        password2 = attrs.get('password2', '')
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("passwords do not mutch")
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user=Users.objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data.get['username'],
            password=validated_data.get['password'],
        )


        return user    

urls.py (app)
from django.urls import path
from .views import RegisterUserView


urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register')
]

urls.py (project)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('api/v1/auth/', include('auth_app.urls')),
]

ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

You've set IsAuthenticated for all views, which with your current setup is also going to hit the Register view. Thus there's no way to sign up and no way to acquire a token.

Acctualy to set an authentication for this api when user wants to register, when he/she has not registered and authenticated in your app yet and you need to say in your views.py
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
also when you  use User and Password it's better to use simple jwt and set an access_token for your user and in postman by passing the access in authorization in berear tap authenticate him
